# Row Editor does not update value object's fields displaying via "columns" tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to devise flexible table containing dynamic columns for CRUD operations.
I use p:columns component to make dynamic columns, but those columns do not change value when I try to update it.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                     var="item"
                     value="#{tableEditorController.items}"
                     editable="true"
                     paginator="true"
                     rows="10"  
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableEditorController.onEdit}" />
        <f:facet name="header">  
            #{tableEditorController.tableName}
        </f:facet>
        <p:columns value="#{tableEditorController.columns}"
                   var="column"
                   columnIndexVar="colIndex">
            <f:facet name="header">#{column.header}</f:facet>
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item[column.property]}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{item[column.property]}" style="width:100%"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:columns>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">test</f:facet>
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item['activityName']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{item['activityName']}" style="width:100%"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:6%">  
            <p:rowEditor />  
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

When I click on link in "Edit" column all the cells in selected row turn into text input fields.
If I edit a value in the "test" column and save, it saves properly as I expect.
But if I edit value using an input field in column which was generated by p:columns tag and try to save, it does not save changes.

I monitored http requests by Chrome Tools. The requests contain changed value in every case.

I ran my code under debugger and a RowEditEvent contains new data in first case and unchanged data object in second.

I cannot realize my mistake <s>and only thing left I doubt is square braces notation.</s>
I checked square braces notation using in "test" column and it works fine.

I use JSF 2.1.3 and Primefaces 3.3

Controller class is following:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TableEditorController {

  private static List activityList;

  static{
      activityList = new ArrayList();

      ActivityType at = new ActivityTypeImpl();
      at.setActivityId(1L);
      at.setActivityName("FirstActivity");
      activityList.add(at);

      at = new ActivityTypeImpl();
      at.setActivityId(2L);
      at.setActivityName("Second Activity");
      activityList.add(at);
  }

  public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event){
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Row Edited");
      msg.setDetail(event.toString() + event.getObject());

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
  }

  public void delete(Object id){

  }

  public List getItems(){
      return activityList;
  }

  public String getTableName(){
      return "Name of the Table";
  }

  public List<ColumnModel> getColumns(){
      ColumnModel m1 = new ColumnModel("ID", "activityId");
      ColumnModel m2 = new ColumnModel("Activity", "activityName");
      return Arrays.asList(m1, m2);
  }

}
```

I will appreciate any suggestion and/or idea.

Comment: Eventually I have updated primefaces to 3.5 and values in generated columns change as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way around p:columns. I replaced it with following code.

```
<c:forEach items="#{tableEditorController.columns}" var="column">
  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">#{column.header}</f:facet>
    <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText value="#{item[column.property]}" />
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
        <p:inputText value="#{item[column.property]}" style="width:100%" disabled="#{not column.editable}"/>
      </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>
</c:forEach>
```

It works but I had to add JSTL library to project dependencies.